# m3u file cannot download it from Xtream and implement it in IPTV application

Tags: android, android-studio, libvlc, m3u, iptv

I am working on `IPTV player` that's going to be implementing a m3u file from `Xtream` but I don't seem to be able to download the m3u file through `Android's DownloadManager` and I cannot use it for direct parsing.

I tried downloading the `m3u file` from the browser and that seems to be going completely fine. But whenever I try to get it from the app itself, it just says download unsuccessful.

The download link to the m3u file is something like this :

```
http://serverip/get.php?username=customeruser&password=customerpassword&type=m3u&output=mpegts
```

Is there anything that I can do to parse this? I cannot seem to be downloading it so maybe using libVLC or EXOPlayer I can parse the list directly.

I am relatively new to Android Studio so any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT: I tried even downloading a simple .jpg file from the DownloadManager and it seems to be working fine, but downloading m3u files is yet still unsuccessful**.

Answer (score 0):

LibVLC can read M3U streams. Try playing your URL in VLC for Android app, if it works, then you can reproduce the same behavior (code is OSS).